# spinner not showing items

Tags: android, android-spinner

i'm trying to add spinner in my code. i think it already right. i just want to show the data in spinner. i'm trying to make it in array or take it from array-string but it always doesn't work

this is my code to add spinner

```
val spinnerItems = resources.getStringArray(R.array.league_event)
    val myStrings = arrayOf("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five")
    Log.v("spinner", ""+myStrings)
    val spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            myStrings)
    lastSpinner?.adapter = spinnerAdapter
```

i trying to add it in fragment. please help if someone knew

Comment: *it always doesn't work* meaning?

Comment: when i tried with arrayOf and string-array it the same doesn't workk

Answer (score 0):

```
val myStrings = arrayOf("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five")
```

// Use `getactivity` keyword instead of `requireactivity()`

```
mySpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(getactivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, myStrings)
```

Try this. Hopefully it will show data in spinner...

Comment: this cannot be used in fragment

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can directly access Activity like:

```
mySpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, myStrings)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.days, R.layout.spinner_item)
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spnDays.adapter = spinnerAdapter
        spnDays.onItemSelectedListener = this
        spnDays.setSelection(0)
```

**spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
```

**string.xml**

```
 <string-array name="days">
        <item>TODAY</item>
        <item>YESTERDAY</item>
        <item>TOMORROW</item>
    </string-array>
```

And at last implement interface OnItemSelectedListener